# Calling functions from a typescript union type array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Typescript array that contains two classes

```
StripeCardModel | StripeBankModel
```

which both extend

```
StripePaymentModel
```

Now I am finding a certain class from the array that can contain two classes and then I want to use the function `achAccountInterfaceObject` on the found class, because if I have found that class, then it is certainly an instance of `StripeBankModel`.

```
let bankPaymentMethod = this.user.stripePaymentMethods.find( paymentMethod => paymentMethod instanceof StripeBankModel );
if ( bankPaymentMethod ) {
    this.bankAccount = bankPaymentMethod.achAccountInterfaceObject;
}
```

Typescript on the other hand tends to disagree with this and give me a compile time error:

```
Property 'achAccountInterfaceObject' does not exist on type 'StripeCardModel | StripeBankModel'.
Property 'achAccountInterfaceObject' does not exist on type 'StripeCardModel'.
```

Could anyone please explain to me how I can write normal code with multityped arrays in typescript without getting these compile time errors?

I have had similar problems with switch cases as like

```
function abc() : Foo|Boo {
    switch ( a.constructor )
    {
        case "Foo":
            a.boo();

        case "Bar":
            a.doo();
    }
}
```

I want to make good code, but typescript is just not letting me do this here. I dont want to break up my code into multiple functions based on class, if the classes are inherited from the same subtree or have similar functionality.

Comment: nedmund's answer is the easiest. You can read more here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html . My 2 cents would be think twice before you have some function like `abc`, it seems to be doing multiple things in 1 place, which is hard to reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no one has a more elegent solution, then casting `bankPaymentMethod` will suppress the compiler errors.

```
this.bankAccount = (<StripePaymentModel>bankPaymentMethod).achAccountInterfaceObject;
```